# Why don't elements pay attention to their absolutely positioned children?

Tags: css, css-position

I'm having trouble with some css.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bkVDH/

I'm trying to make `#window`'s height stem from what's in `.content`. `.content` is absolutely positioned, but in a way that you can figure out the height of `.wrap` if you know the height of the content div. The same is true between `.wrap` and `#window`, so I was hoping that since `.content` has a height due to what's inside of it, `#window` would to, but it's not working.

Is this solvable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely-positioned children go out of the normal flow an cannot affect parent's height, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The point of absolute positioning an element is to take it out of the flow of the document, i.e. stop it from affecting its parent element, sibling elements, etc.

What reason do you have for absolutely positioning `.content`?

Comment: I think I'm overusing absolute positioning, so I'm starting to think I need it everywhere when conventional methods work fine. It was because I had another `<div>` inside `.content` that I'd also absolute positioned for no good reason. And it's 3 a.m. here. Thanks

Comment: I think it's something we've all done at least once! No sweat.